# Как отключить желтую подсказку в новой версии Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Как отключить желтую подсказку в новой версии Android Studio? в версии 1.5 такого не было. Листаю код и каждый раз вылазит эта подсказка и пролистывание останавливается. Помогите выключить ее. Если надо, я комбинацией клавиш вызвать ее смогу.А он автоматическая при наведении мышки сейчас.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Show quick doc on mouse move не работает. Так как в настройках не стоит галочка но данная функция работает

Comment: Можете добавить аннотацию @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") перед вашим методом или перед классом.

Comment: @Соколов, могу). А есть возможность отключить авто показ при наведении мышки? Суть в том что из за этого у меня студия тупить начинает. Раздражает это все ибо ты пишешь что то и мышкой коснулся этих желтых пунктиров и все прога виснет на 30 сек. Реально раздражает

Comment: так может лучше исправить проблему? Ведь это не подсказка, а warning

Comment: `HashMap details = new HashMap();` поменяйте на `Map<String, Object> details = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @YuraIvanov, в чем подвох то? почему не нравиться ему HashMap?

Comment: Данный warning говорит о том, что вы проверку типов переносите с этапа компиляции в рантайм, добавляя во-первых, оверхеда в рантайме, во-вторых, не гарантируете безопасность типов. полный ответ здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it